# jQuery this.VarName is it possible?

Tags: jquery, variables, this

So in short what I am trying to do is on a click event of a specific element ie (.beanHolder ul li) I want to subtract from a score (.score) then declare a variable (clicked = "yes") so then when the user clicks that item again the second part of the code is processed. I know that the lengthy way would be to declare a var for each of the .beans (this would be at least 40 vars) and as such the code could become rather lengthy. My thought process is that I'd be able to add the variable to the bean using "this" but in practice it doesn't work out. Any thoughts would be grand!!!

My jQuery Code ->

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var clicked = "";
$(".beanHolder ul li").click(function(){

    if (this.clicked == "")
    {
        $(".bean", this).attr("src", "img/bean.png");
        var number = parseInt($('#score').text());
        number-=1;
        $('#score').text(number);
        this.clicked = "yes";
        return;
    }
    else if (this.clicked == "yes")
    {
        $(".bean", this).attr("src", "img/beanG.png");
        var number = parseInt($('#score').text());
        number+=1;
        $('#score').text(number);
        this.clicked = "";
        return; 
    }
}); 
});
</script>
```

edit: I got it working; if someone is looking for something similar this will work ->

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".beanHolder ul li").click(function(){
    //$(this).data("clicked","no");
    var clicked = $(this).data("clicked");

    if (clicked)
    {
        $(".bean", this).attr("src", "img/beanG.png");
        var number = parseInt($('#score').text());
        number+=1;
        $('#score').text(number);
        $(this).data("clicked",false);
        //var clicked = $(this).data("clicked");
        //return;
    }
    else
    {       
//This is to keep the score from going below 0; as it is it can not go over a score of 20.
        if (parseInt($('#score').text()) > -1) 
        {
            $(".bean", this).attr("src", "img/bean.png");
            var number = parseInt($('#score').text());
            number-=1;
            $('#score').text(number);
            $(this).data("clicked",true);
            //return;
        }
    }
}); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: you could use [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to add data (variables) to DOM elements. Please post some markup as well

Comment: Posted an edit with the revised working version using the .data method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to attach arbitrary data to a DOM element:

```
$(this).data("clicked","yes");
```

And you can retrieve it later with:

```
var clicked = $(this).data("clicked");
```

So, putting it all together you could do something like this:

```
$(".beanHolder ul li").click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).data("clicked");
    if (clicked) {
        // this element has been clicked
        $(this).data("clicked",false);    // I'd much rather use bools than "yes"/"no"
    }
    else {
        // clicked hasn't been clicked
        $(this).data("clicked",true);    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the attribute like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".beanHolder ul li").click(function(){
    var clicked = $( this ).attr( 'clicked' );
    if (clicked == "")
    {
       ...
    }
    else if (this.clicked == "yes")
    {
      ...
    }
}); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is very similer to a method I tried earlier. I didn't know you could add the .attr to this but I think it could/should work. I went with the other answer because I think it is a better way of accomplishing my goals. But thanks for the quick response!!!